# Unity ECS on linux error when trying to start new 2D project

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, entity-component-system, unity-dots

I have installed Unity on linux and everithing seems to work as expected when developing games in the standard model. However when I set up a project for ECS development, by installing the following packages:

- Burst 1.3.0
- Entities 0.11.0
- Hybrid renderer 0.5.1
- Jobs 0.2.10
- Mathematics 1.1.0

I get the following error when creating a blank 2D project:

```
Library/PackageCache/com.unity.2d.animation@3.2.2/Runtime/TransformAccessJob.cs(196,62): error CS1061: 'NativeHashMap<int, TransformAccessJob.TransformData>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no accessible extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'NativeHashMap<int, TransformAccessJob.TransformData>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Unity version: 2019.3.14f1 Personal

Anyone has any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: remove the animations package, as ecs animaions are not really real

Comment: This solved it. Thank you. You should make it an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the 2D Animation package is not a valid option for me since I am using the 2D skeleton animation functionalities it provides.

This problem seems to result from the API change with Jobs 0.2.10.
Downgrading Jobs to 0.2.9 solved this problem for me.

Comment: thank you man, you saved my day. I'd like to point out that you'll need to downgrade also a couple of other packages, if your're using them, as they depended on the last version of Jobs; like Entities and Hybrid Renderer.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix if you want to use the animation package is to change `m_TransformData.Length` to `m_TransformData.Count()` in the line specified in the error (`TransformAccessJob.cs` line 196).